# Lilypond: How can I map numbers to notes with Scheme

Tags: lilypond

I'm trying to create a function where, for an example, `\generateNote #3 #4` would generate an f4 - this would help to write functions to quickly generate scales etc.

```
generateNote = 
#(define-music-function
  (parser location note)
  (number?)
  (define notes 
      '((0 . "c4") 
        (1 . "d4") 
        (2 . "e4") 
        (3 . "f4") 
        (4 . "g4") 
        (5 . "a4") 
        (6 . "b4")))
  #{  #(cdr (assoc (modulo note 7) notes)) #}
  )
```

This does not work because `error: music function cannot generate f4`. The following, however, does work:

```
generateF = 
#(define-music-function
  (parser location)
  #{  f4 #}
  )
```

Any thoughts about why this isn't working?

I already tried swapping the `" "` with `{ }` and `#{ #}` to no avail.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been asked better and answered here https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/40379/lilypond-function-to-interpolate-two-notes/43551#43551

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get something going with

```
generateNote = 
    #(define-music-function
     (parser location note duration) 
        (number? number?) 
        (define notes 
          '((0 . "c") 
            (1 . "d") 
            (2 . "e") 
            (3 . "f") 
            (4 . "g") 
            (5 . "a") 
            (6 . "b"))) 
        #{ 
            $(ly:parser-include-string 
              parser 
              (string-append 
                (cdr (assoc (modulo note 7) notes))
                (number->string duration)
                )
              )
        #}
       )
```

It at least works.